# Naming Triggers and Sequences - Oracle Data Modeler

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I'm trying to use the table name to name triggers and sequences in Oracle Data Modeler. 
I try to use {table} pattern in the field, but when I generate the DDL the table name is not applied to the name.

How can I use a table name to name triggers and sequences automatically?

[image]

Comment: I don't know if there is a technical solution to your question (not familiar with Data Modeler) but do have some observations about your naming conventions for sequences and triggers.  First, why do you have one object type named <prefix>_<table>, and the other named <table_suffix>.  Why not be consistent, putting the 'type identifier) as _always_ a prefix or _always a suffix. Yes, I can be OCD, but 40 years of dealing with misleading naming conventions will do that to you.  Second, and more important, what if you later need multiple triggers on a given table?

Comment: @EdStevens, that is a standard from the organization. We need to name triggers and sequences in this way. That trigger is specific for autoincrement, other triggers will be handled as we needed. But every table have an autoincrement trigger, this is default in oracle.

Comment: Actually, having an autoincrement trigger is NOT a default in oracle. It may very well be a 'default' standard in your organization, but not in oracle itself.  My question about what will you do if you have to have additional triggers on a given table has to do with the fact that your naming standard for triggers _appears_ to be 'fixed', with no room for additional names.  If you have ways of handling it, that's fine.  It's just my observation, after a long career of creating and enforcing consistent and extensible naming standards for all sorts of entities.  :-)